# How to filter a model with respect to text and then use most_similar?

Tags: python, model, nltk, word2vec

I have the text and I want to filter the model with respect to the text. It is OK?

```
import pandas as pd
import gensim
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.collocations import *
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
import re

text = "though quite simple room solid choice allocated room already used summer holiday apartment bel endroit nice place place winter"
from gensim.models import Word2Vec,  KeyedVectors

model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz')
model_filter = [w for w in list(model.wv.vocab) if w in text]
```

If it is OK how to filter in the results (model_filter ) of the most similar function (modelo_filtrado.most_similar_cosmul????), those that belong to the text?
Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `text` is a plain string. The words inside the `model` are individual word strings. So, your existing check is looking to see if individual words appear *anywhere* as substrings inside your `text`.

For example, even though `'ice'` does not appear in your `text` as a word, this will evaluate as `True`:

```
'ice' in "though quite simple room solid choice allocated room already used summer holiday apartment bel endroit nice place place winter"
```

You probably want to turn your `text` into a list of words, first:

```
text_words = text.split()
```

Otherwise, yes, your code will fille `model_filter` with only those words that are both in the `model` and `in` your `text` (or `text_words`).